# Change an <img> elements by hovering an other <img>

Tags: html, css, hover

As I said in the title, I would like to change an img by hovering an other img. My first img that I will hover will be called "voir-plus-mini-img-avant" and the second img will be called "voir-plus-img-avant".

Here's my html code :

```
<div class="voir-plus-container">
    <div class="voir-plus-mini-img">
        <img src="file:///C:/HTML/vente-de-guitares/guitare-img/guitare.jpg" class="voir-plus-mini-img-avant">
    </div>
    <div class="voir-plus-image">
        <img src="file:///C:/HTML/vente-de-guitares/guitare-img/guitare.jpg" class="voir-plus-img-avant">
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CCS

```
.voir-plus-mini-img-avant:hover ~ .voir-plus-img-avant {
    display: block;
}

.voir-plus-img-avant {
    display: none;
}
```

So when you hover "voir-plus-mini-img-avant" the "voir-plus-img-avant" gets to be desplayed as a block. Normaly, "voir-plus-img-avant" wont be displayed. I saw by doing reseach that ~ is when you want to do an action on an other  by hovering one. But it isn't working :(

So if you could help me, it would be nice :)

Ps : I can't put the 1st img into the other big div because the 2 images arent the same size and stuff.

Comment: `~` is the general sibling selector, however your images are not siblings of one another. Also, there's no parent selector in CSS, so what you're after can't be done purely in CSS yet; you'd need JavaScript. Or you could select the parent div container instead of the image.

Comment: Thanks but for the parent div I can't because I have got much more images in the divs so I have to chose one image... :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/roufhj8m/

Or more like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/s4q40yxj/2/

html

```
<div class="thumbs-div">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/c0lfxLU.png" class="small s1">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yfNIfVR.jpg" class="small s2">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0hLtbEh.jpg" class="small s3">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sVUEr5j.jpg" class="small s4">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XCbY5Di.jpg" class="small s5">

    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/c0lfxLU.png" class="big b1">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yfNIfVR.jpg" class="big b2">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0hLtbEh.jpg" class="big b3">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sVUEr5j.jpg" class="big b4">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XCbY5Di.jpg" class="big b5">
</div>
```

css

```
.thumbs-div {
    width: 520px;
}

.small {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.big {
    width: 516px;
    height: 300px;
}

.b1 {
    display: block;
}

.b2, .b3, .b4, .b5 {
    display: none;
}

.s2:hover ~ .b2, .s3:hover ~ .b3, .s4:hover ~ .b4, .s5:hover ~ .b5 {
    display: block;
}

.s2:hover ~ .b1, .s3:hover ~ .b1, .s4:hover ~ .b1, .s5:hover ~ .b1 {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: The original question states that the two images can't be in the same div.

Comment: But in 2 different div :c If I don't have my answer, i'll have to use only 1 div ._.

Comment: Like j08691 mentioned above, doesn't look to be possible in 2 divs with strictly CSS so I thought I'd post other options. Glad it helped. Lots of other ways to go about it and tweak it, let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.voir-plus-container .voir-plus-image,
.voir-plus-container:hover .voir-plus-mini-img {
    display: none;
}

.voir-plus-container:hover .voir-plus-image {
    display: block;
}
```

`div.voir-plus-image` will be hidden by default, on hover it will be displayed and `div.voir-plus-mini-img` will be hidden.

Comment: Can't get this to work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPYYMJ, am I missing anything?

Comment: @cdMinix You are using the same image. You should use different images to see difference. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEwogR

Answer (score 0):

The css `+` selector selects all elements immediately after another element. If your order of elements doesn't change, this solution might work for you:

```
.voir-plus-image > .voir-plus-img-avant {
  display: none;
}

.voir-plus-mini-img:hover + .voir-plus-image > .voir-plus-img-avant  {
  display: block;
}
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPELBq for demonstration.

The only letdown of this css-only solution is that you have to depend on the `div`, not the `img` for hovering. If you can't have that, your only alternative would be javascript.

Comment: Thanks cdMinix but i'd like to hover the .voir-plus-mini-img-avant. With the "avant" because actually, I've got plenty of images so I want to select only one to desplay an other. And I will repeat this for my 4 photos.

Comment: You can only achieve this using javascript, or by putting all images in the same div.

Comment: I wont use javascript cus it's too complicated for me so i'd be better putting all the images in to the same div

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to do this.

Is several way to hover that element. I recomend you to do this like:

1) create a new class like .active;
2) add display none to your both image
3) create jquery function. I wrote example here `[https://jsfiddle.net/bvnaqL2s/][1]`